# How to implement factory pattern better with spring boot native support?

Tags: java, spring-boot, factory-pattern

Best way to implement factory pattern in Spring boot.

I've an interface and multiple implementations of it. During a request, I need to return the bean based on an input string.

There are multiple ways I can do it.. But whats the best way?

```
interface vehicle {
void drive();
string getVehicleName();
}

@Component
public class Car implements vehicle {
  private static string prop = "car";
  @Override
  string getVehicleName() { return prop;}

  @Override
  void drive() {}
}

@Component
public class Bike implements vehicle {
  private static string prop = "bike";

  @Override
  string getVehicleName() { return prop;}

  @Override
  void drive() {}
}

@Service
public class VehicleFactory {
    @Autowired
    private List<vehicle> vehicles;

    private static final HashMap<String, vehicle> requestVehicleMap = new HashMap<>();

    @PostConstruct
    public void initVehicleFactory() {
        for(vehicle vehicle : vehicles) {
            requestVehicleMap.put(vehicle.getVehicleName(), request);
        }
    }

    public static vehicle getVehicleImpl(String vehicleName) {
        return requestVehicleMap.get(vehicleName);
    }
}
```

This does give me correct class.
Also there is "qualifier" that can be used as [Implementing custom factory pattern in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16896646/implementing-custom-factory-pattern-in-spring).

But is there better approach?

Comment: Two questions: 1. where does  private List<vehicle> vehicles; come from? 2. Is a vehicle a spring component, a DTO or an entity?

Comment: I do agree with Simon.  @Harshini, your question "But is there better approach?", in what sense ? Please make the question more specific so that others can help you.

Comment: List of vehicles is auto wired using spring... So it would've all implementations. Also when I say better way, I mean to ask whether spring boot provides any better way of doing this..

Answer (score 1):

Interface and it's Implementation are good, I would just change the Factory class alone because you already I got the List of Implementation then Why again to initialise it in a Map

I will also comment the suggestions in the code

### VehicleFactory

```java
@Service
public class VehicleFactory {

    @Autowired
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public Vehicle getVehicleImpl(String vehicleName) { // You have already declared as @Service then why use static
          return vehicles.stream()
                .filter(vehicle -> vehicle.getVehicleName().equalsIgnoreCase(vehicleName)) // This will filter the Impl you needed from others
                .findFirst() 
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException(String.format(" Invlaid Vehicle Name - %s", vehicleName))); // Incase Impl is not found it should throw an error or handle in some other ways
    }
}
```

So give it a try

Comment: Yes this would work too.. But my point is to have cleaner implementation and also use any inbuilt support from spring.